# AWS SDK in java - How to get activities from worker when multple execution on going for a state machine

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-step-functions

**AWS Step Function**

My problem is to how to sendTaskSuccess or sendTaskFailuer to Activity which are running under the state machine  in AWS .

My Actual intent is to Notify the specific activities which belongs to particular State machine execution.

I successfully send notification to all waiting activities by activityARN. But my actual need is to send notification to specific activity which belong to particular state machine execution .

Example . StateMachine - SM1
There two execution on going for SM1-- SM1E1, SM1E2 . In that case I want to sendTaskSuccess to activity which belongs to SM1E1 .

follwoing code i used . But it send notification to all activities

```
        GetActivityTaskResult getActivityTaskResult = client.getActivityTask(new GetActivityTaskRequest()
                .withActivityArn("arn detail"));

        if (getActivityTaskResult.getTaskToken() != null) {
            try {
                JsonNode json = Jackson.jsonNodeOf(getActivityTaskResult.getInput());

                    String outputResult = patientRegistrationActivity.setStatus(json.get("patientId").textValue());
                    System.out.println("outputResult " + outputResult);
                    SendTaskSuccessRequest sendTaskRequest = new SendTaskSuccessRequest().withOutput(outputResult)
                            .withTaskToken(getActivityTaskResult.getTaskToken());
                    client.sendTaskSuccess(sendTaskRequest);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                client.sendTaskFailure(
                        new SendTaskFailureRequest().withTaskToken(getActivityTaskResult.getTaskToken()));
            }
```

Comment: I answered a similar question in here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55979328/aws-getactivitytask-beloging-from-the-same-state-machine-execution/58440488#58440488

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a POC to check and below is the solution .

if token is consumed by `getActivityTaskResult.getTaskToken()` and if your conditions not satisfied by  request input then you can  use below line to avoid token consumption `.awsStepFunctionClient.sendTaskHeartbeat(new SendTaskHeartbeatRequest().withTaskToken(taskToken))`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you have no control over which task token is returned. You may get one for SM1E1 or SM1E2 and you cannot tell by looking at the task token. [GetActivityTask](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_GetActivityTask.html) returns "input" so based on that you may be able to tell which execution you are dealing with but if you get a token you are not interested in, I don't think there's a way to put it back so you won't be able to get it again with [GetActivityTask](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_GetActivityTask.html) later. I guess you could store it in a database somewhere for use later.

One idea you can try is to use the new [callback](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-to-resource.html#connect-wait-token) integration pattern. You can specify the Payload parameter in the state definition to include the task token like this `token.$: "$$.Task.Token"` and then use [GetExecutionHistory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_GetExecutionHistory.html) to find the *TaskScheduled* state of the execution you are interested in and retrieve the `parameters.Payload.token` value and then use that with *sendTaskSuccess*.

Here's a snippet of my serverless.yml file that describes the state

```
WaitForUserInput: #Wait for the user to do something
    Type: Task
    Resource: arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke.waitForTaskToken
    Parameters:
        FunctionName:
        Fn::GetAtt: [WaitForUserInputLambdaFunction, Arn]
        Payload:
        token.$: "$$.Task.Token"
        executionArn.$: "$$.Execution.Id"
    Next: DoSomethingElse
```

Comment: I didn’t get it completely . Can you share some example snnipet here. Just to add on what i did yet to get that . But that not worked .  I get input json and based on the json attribute I put if conditions but that also not make any impact .